# Advanced table sorting in lua

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table

I am attempting to sort an advanced table, but not succeeding.

Here is what my table structure looks like:

```
{
    ["12345"] = {12345, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
    ["523544"] = {523544, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
    ["6744"] = {6744, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
    ["146"] = {146, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
    ["724572"] = {724572, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
    ["54"] = {54, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
    ["146"] = {146, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
    ["146"] = {146, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
    ["12345"] = {12345, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
    ["44"] = {44, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
}
```

and I would like to sort it from greatest to least like so:

```
{
    ["724572"] = {724572, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
    ["523544"] = {523544, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
    ["12345"] = {12345, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
    ["12345"] = {12345, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
    ["6744"] = {6744, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
    ["146"] = {146, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
    ["146"] = {146, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
    ["146"] = {146, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
    ["54"] = {54, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
    ["44"] = {44, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
}
```

I am running into a few problems here.

1. It can't save 2 numbers of equal value
2. I can't seem to sort it properly from greatest to least

As for why the indexes are strings, if I do `table[623258195] = "Example"`, the table would create 623258195 indexes, causing my program to crash.

As for why the values are tables, it stores other important information, which is what the 2nd and 3rd values in the table are, the 1st being an number form of the index.

I hope I'm being clear, and I'm sorry if this would be considered a duplicate question, I have not found anything in the last hour of searching that has assisted me.

Comment: You can't sort tables without using integer keys. You can create a second table that's ordered, with integer keys, with values that are equal to the corresponding key in the unsorted table. I'll post an example in a bit.

Comment: Also -- Using `table[largenum]` will not (should not?) create indexes up to `largenum`.

Comment: I tested `table[largenum]` again, and it appears as though you're correct, though I recall running into this issue a while ago.

Comment: However, I still can't use indexes to hold the values, as I need to be able to hold multiple of the same number. I will experiment around with what you said in the meantime.

Comment: "if I do table[623258195] = "Example", the table would create 623258195 indexes" Which implementation of Lua behaves that way? The standard one doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

1. You'll need to modify your data structure, to support multiple values with the same id/key:

   ```
   {
       [12345] = {
           {12345, "foo", {"bar"}}, -- You'll probably want to sort these somehow.
           {12345, "baz", {"qux"}}
       },
       [123] = {
           {123, "foo", {"bar"}}
       }
   }
   ```
2. You can use `table.sort(tbl, f)`, along with an index table:

   ```
   local unsorted = {} -- Data, in your format, inside this table.
   local index = {} -- Table which will contain sorted keys (then you loop over this, get unsorted[k])
   for k in pairs(unsorted) do
       index[#index+1] = k -- Populate the keys to sort.
   end
   table.sort(index, function(a, b) 
    return b < a -- Order highest to lowest, instead of lowest - highest (default)
   end)
   ```

Here's the full code sample, and results. http://ideone.com/thE1zP

Comment: Let me know if you need more explanation. For multiple keys, I forgot to mention, you'll just want to branch out: `tbl[1234] = {[1] = {1234, "data"}, [2] = {1234, "otherdata"}}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can't "sort" keys in a hash as they don't have "order" in the way the integer sequence of keys in a table does.

You can change the data structure to turn the hash into a table, but an easier way may be to have a separate table with just the hash keys and sort their values; when you need to get the elements from the hash in a particular order, you simply go through the (sorted) elements in that table and then retrieve the elements from the hash.

In either case you won't be able to store multiple values for the same key as you are attempting to do:

```
{
...
    ["146"] = {146, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
    ["146"] = {146, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
    ["146"] = {146, "Something", {"Stuff"}},
...
}
```

You need to store them in a table (and reference that table using `"146"` key) or rethink why you need different elements keys by the same key value.